# Saving a list of ScriptableObject into json

Tags: c#, json, save

My Item script

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName ="Newitems",menuName ="Inventory/Items")]
[Serializable]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{

  new public string name = "New items";  
  //public Sprite Icon = null;      dealt with this later        
  public bool isDefaulet = false;
  ...}
```

And here is my inventory script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
[Serializable]
public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
   [SerializeField]
public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
 void Save()
    {
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(items);
        Debug.Log(json);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/saveFile.json", json);
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/saveFile.json");
        List<Item> List = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Item>>(json);
        Debug.Log(List);
    }
...
 }
```

Ok, i will try with the sprite later, but when saving, the console return {}, i have no idea now, please help.

Comment: C# and UnityScript are two different languages. Please don't tag unnecessary languages. I've removed the `unityscript` tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first things to save your scriptable in json is to add the class attribute Serializable on each scriptable you want to serialize in json.

But here I think it will be hard to serialize the Icon field. In a json you really can save only number or string and there is a reference.

A way to serialize a Sprite ( or any reference) is to serialize the name or the id of the object. If you look how unity serialize a scene it’s exactly how it’s done.
And then when you read your json you replace that id by your asset.

Some json library can help on that, NewtonSoft Json.Net can help, specially on the special serialization for reference I describe.

Try it without the Sprite first and add complexity after ;)

EDIT

To be more precise, I think the better way to do what your try, is to not serialize a ScriptableObject, but instead a class hold by the scriptable.

```
class MyScriptable : ScriptableObject
{
    private MySerializableClass data;
}

[Serializable]
class MySerializableClass 
{
    private string name;
    private float data1;
    private float data2;
}
```

Then serialize the MySerializableClass, and use the name, or some id field to link each instance of scriptable with the good MySerializableClass :)

Comment: Ok, So i will try with Sprite later but i'm still cannot serialize my list, i have edit my question, please check it!

Comment: What the problem on that ? You can try by not serialize directly your ScripatbleObject. But instead serialize only a field of your SO, this field can be a class that contain all your basic data